# Javascript cannot find php file on localhost

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send string data to a php script on localhost:8080 to be saved, but the Javascript function cannot find the php file and gives a 404 error.

This is the Javascript:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , myStringData);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/Source/ServerInputManager.php", true);
xhr.send(data);
```

This is the ServerInputManager.php script:

```php
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "NewFile.txt";

    $file = fopen($fname, 'w'); // Creates new file
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

I know the php file exists because I can download it from that URL in chrome.  I can also read the contents with a GET request using that URL.  But whenever I try to use POST, it gives a 404 error.  I am not using any php libraries, but I am using node to run a server.js script.

This is the file structure:

```
|- index.html
|- index.css
|- server.js (ran by node)
+- Source
   |- InputManager.js (contains the javascript code)
   +- ServerInputManager.php (contains the php code)
```

I've also tried using these directories:

```
http://localhost:8080/Source/ServerInputManager.php
http://localhost:8080/ServerInputManager.php
localhost:8080/Source/ServerInputManager.php
localhost:8080/ServerInputManager.php
/Source/ServerInputManager.php
Source/ServerInputManager.php
/ServerInputManager.php
ServerInputManager.php
```

But they all gave 404 errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't provided enough info. 1) Are you using any type of PHP framework or library? 2) can you provide an idea of your file structure on the server.

Comment: Ok now with your including your file structure: so are you using Express as your server? Do you have `app.use()` or `app.get()` and `app.post()` in your `server.js` file?

Comment: I'll just say it making a ton of assumptions: you have no POST "route" to: `/Source/ServerInputManager.php` in your Express router setup.

Comment: I didn't write the server.js file, but it does have a few app.use() and app.get() calls.  None of them are related to the ServerInputManager.php script or the /Source folder.

Comment: Well, I suppose you've discovered that you cannot copy-n-paste a file, launch a server and expect things _just to work_ without understanding how the moving parts fit together. Perhaps you can start here (focusing on the part about "What are Routes"): https://www.guru99.com/node-js-express.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess this js file runs on a client browser and it was served by the same server that holds your php app.

If that's the case, then you should expose an endpoint on the server side that expects POST requests on some url like `/input` (for example).

Then your js code should be:

```
xhr.open('POST', "/input", true);
xhr.send(data);
```

Remember: you don't perform POST requests directly to php files but to a server that works with php. The server shall receive the POST request on /input and delegate the processing of said request to ServerInputManager.php (or delegate all requests to ServerInputManager.php and only process POST requests on /input).

Hope this helps

Comment: How does the server know what script to delegate the request to?

Comment: Well that depends on your php app and what framework you're using. If you're using something like laravel then you would have a file with routes like `Route::post('/input', function () {
    doSomething(); // calls logic on ServerInputManager.php
});`

Comment: Check this tutorial for a basic crud app with php and laravel: https://appdividend.com/2019/03/08/laravel-5-8-crud-tutorial-with-example-for-beginners/

Comment: And if the OP is not using a framework like Laravel?

Comment: Then you will have to handle routing manually using pure php. Here's how to handle data received: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Here's how to handle routing: https://joshtronic.com/2015/05/24/basic-page-routing-in-php/

Comment: @MartínZaragoza - your answer in regards to how PHP relates to a HTTP server is no longer relevant as the OP has now disclosed he is using Node and Express to serve his app.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,

I found Randy Casburn's comment most useful

> you have no POST 'route' to /Source/ServerInputManager.php in your Express router setup.

Although I did not exactly solve the problem, I found another way to get to the same result.

This is the new Javascript code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/targetInput", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: myStringData,
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

This is what I added to my server.js script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
app.post('/targetInput', function(request, response) {
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString();
        // Do whatever with the string data on the server

        response.end("Success!");
    });
});
```

The php file is no longer used.